# How to use jose library in angularjs . #622

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Could anyone please provide a sample code snippet demonstrating how to integrate this library into an AngularJS application? We also have Gulp files in place for minification and bundling.

I have installed the jose library using npm i jose, and it's present in the node_modules folder. I've added references to this library in the app.html pages, but when the pages load, I'm encountering an 'Unexpected export token' error.

Angularjs version -1.8

https://github.com/panva/jose